# How can i print the value from one array which has corresponding value from other array

Tags: java, arrays

For example

1. array   dogNames { Charlie, Luis, Annie}
2. array  isdogcolorRed { true, false, false}

how can i print the name of the dog which has corresponding value from isdogcolorRed array?

Comment: Off topic: With a good Object-Oriented design, you could have a `class Dog` with a "name" property and a "color" property. For each `Dog` object, the name and color could be assigned during construction.

Comment: Step through `isdogcolorRed` with a for loop like for `(int i = 0; i < isdogcolorRed.length; i++)` . When the indexed value is `true` , use the value of the index (`i`) to get the matching name from `dogNames`.

Answer (score 1):

This code does the job

```
    List<String> dogNames = List.of("Charlie", "Luis", "Annie");
    List<Boolean> isDogColorRed = List.of(true, false, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < isDogColorRed.size(); i++) {
        if (isDogColorRed.get(i))
            System.out.println(dogNames.get(i));
    }
```